# How to use template partials in MASK Extension

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x

I need to render a partial from my Main Template (SitePackage) within a MASK content element. The partial is located in the folder *Resources/Private/Partials* and the fluid code of my content element is located in *Resources/Private/Extensions/Mask/Frontend/Templates*.

This is my (testing) partial (Test.html):

```
<div class="header">
    <h3>Dies ist ein Partial</h3>
</div>
```

In the MASK content element I try to render it with `<f:render partial="Test"/>`, but it doesen't work, the page is showing the following error message:

*The Fluid template files "[...]/Resources/Private/Extensions/Mask/Frontend/Partials/Test.html", "[...]/Resources/Private/Extensions/Mask/Frontend/Partials/Test" could not be loaded.*).

Is there a way to render a partial from outside my *Extension* folder?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Like for any FLUID templating you can add further paths to select layout, template or partial.
Just add the further paths with new numbers to the list of these paths.

In mask you define the paths like:

```
module.tx_mask.view {
   layoutRootPaths.30 = EXT:your_site_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts
   partialRootPaths.30 = EXT:your_site_extension/Resources/Private/Partials
   templateRootPaths.30 = EXT:your_site_extension/Resources/Private/Templates
}
plugin.tx_mask.view {
   layoutRootPaths.30 = EXT:your_site_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts
   partialRootPaths.30 = EXT:your_site_extension/Resources/Private/Partials
   templateRootPaths.30 = EXT:your_site_extension/Resources/Private/Templates
}
```

> Mind the plural -s in "layoutRootPaths", "templateRootPaths" &  "partialRootPaths"! > [TYPO3 Docs - FLUIDTEMPLATE](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html)

But be careful if you mix different templating sets like page-templates, mask-/CE-templates, news-templates, ....
**you might get naming conflicts!!**